# Copy list1 property to list2 based oncondition

Tags: c#, linq

I have one list with some properties:

```
public class Class1
{
    public int Id;
    public string Name;
}
List<Class1> list1 = GetSomeData()
```

After this step I have filled all Id in list1 but Names are empty. I have also second list where are filled these values like this:

```
public class Class2
{
    public int Id;
    public string Name;
}
List<Class2> list2 = GetSomeData()
```

So list2 has filled Ids and Names - Ids are same as list1 but of course on anothers indexes.

Is possible to fill property name in list1 with Name from list2 dependently on Ids through linq? 
I have tried something like this, but it doesn't work. I am only able to get Names to array or (new) list, but not to list1.

```
list1.Join(list2,
            l2 => l2.Id,
            l1 => l1.Id,
            (l1, l2) => { l1.Name = l2.Name; return l1.Name; });
```

Or this - but there is a problem with new clause so I am not able to save it to the list1 again.

```
(from l1 in list1
    join l2 in list2
    on l1.Id equals l2.Id
    select new { l1.Name = l2.Name });
```

thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach you have is workable, but note that enumerables are lazy-evaluated.  Your code sets up an enumerable sequence, but does not actually step through the enumeration -- as a result the setters never get invoked.

One way to force the enumeration is to add `ToList()` to the end of your statement:

```
list1.Join(list2,
        l2 => l2.Id,
        l1 => l1.Id,
        (l1, l2) => { l1.Name = l2.Name; return l1.Name; })
        .ToList();
```

This does seem counter-intuitive, but your approach is also a bit unorthodox -- it's probably unwise generally to change properties inside enumeration blocks like that.  I think it would be better (clearer and safer, even if a bit more verbose) to use a `ForEach` iterator to set the property:

```
list1.Join(list2,
        l2 => l2.Id,
        l1 => l1.Id,
        (l1, l2) => new { l1 = l1, l2 = l2 })
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(x => {
        x.l1.Name = x.l2.Name;
    });
```